# Does Android Studio 3.0 add parameter prompt information?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

The following sample code maded by Kotlin is shown in Android Studio 3.0, I find the `fun detailIntent.putExtra("Person", SampleData.BOB)` is shown as `detailIntent.putExtra(name: "Person", SampleData.BOB)`, and I can't delete `name` in the editor.

It seems that Android Studio 3.0 add parameter prompt information name,  right? and how can I set  to turn on or turn off it?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`It seems that Android Studio 3.0 add parameter prompt information name`  - Yes.

`and how can I set to turn on or turn off it?`

**Disable**, just right click on hint place :-

[image]

**Enable**, the same way :-

[image]

If you facing issues with click, change it from settings :-

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I can disable, but I can't find the item Enable  Parameter Name Hints, would you please see the image  https://www.dropbox.com/s/ev9crcg2sqgutw6/bb.PNG?dl=0

Comment: @HelloCW because your cursor in wrong place, your cursor should be before or after the word, or parameter  seperator  " , "

Comment: Thanks! you are right! But the item Enable Parameter Name Hints doesn't display when I locate my cursor before or after the word  SampleData.BOB , why?

Comment: @HelloCW it dosen't displayed because no hint on SampleData.BOB, the hint on first parameter